# stlread in MATLAB returns different numbers of vertices/points

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB R2019b. I have to edit a `.m` file which uses an accompanied `stlread()`. This one returns a struct stl, and I can use `stl.vertices` to get the points of the model.

From [R2018b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) onwards, the `stlread()` and `stlwrite()` seem to be completely rewritten, returning a triangulation stl. The points are accessed through `stl.Points`. However, the number of points (as well as the loading time) drastically reduce. This new `stlread()` loads my sample file 5 times faster, and produces 10 times smaller number of points.

What really changed in the new `stlread()`? Can I directly modify `stl.Points` (e.g. rotate the point cloud,...)?

**Update:** This is the `stlread.m` file that came with my assignment. I think it's from an older version of MATLAB.

```matlab
function varargout = stlread(file)
% STLREAD imports geometry from an STL file into MATLAB.
%    FV = STLREAD(FILENAME) imports triangular faces from the ASCII or binary
%    STL file idicated by FILENAME, and returns the patch struct FV, with fields
%    'faces' and 'vertices'.
%
%    [F,V] = STLREAD(FILENAME) returns the faces F and vertices V separately.
%
%    [F,V,N] = STLREAD(FILENAME) also returns the face normal vectors.
%
%    The faces and vertices are arranged in the format used by the PATCH plot
%    object.
% Copyright 2011 The MathWorks, Inc.
    if ~exist(file,'file')
        error(['File ''%s'' not found. If the file is not on MATLAB''s path' ...
               ', be sure to specify the full path to the file.'], file);
    end

    fid = fopen(file,'r');    
    if ~isempty(ferror(fid))
        error(lasterror); %#ok
    end

    M = fread(fid,inf,'uint8=>uint8');
    fclose(fid);

    [f,v,n] = stlbinary(M);
    %if( isbinary(M) ) % This may not be a reliable test
    %    [f,v,n] = stlbinary(M);
    %else
    %    [f,v,n] = stlascii(M);
    %end

    varargout = cell(1,nargout);
    switch nargout        
        case 2
            varargout{1} = f;
            varargout{2} = v;
        case 3
            varargout{1} = f;
            varargout{2} = v;
            varargout{3} = n;
        otherwise
            varargout{1} = struct('faces',f,'vertices',v);
    end
end
```

Comment: "From R2018b onwards, the stlread() and stlwrite() seem to be completely rewritten", I am confused, stlread was introduced in MATLAB 2018b, did you previously use 3rd party code?

Comment: @Daniel Please see my update.